# Split best seller and new arrivals in prestashop

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'll like to split best seller and new arrival blocks in two rows. So there is a title with "NUEVOS" with the new arrivals products then below a title again "LOS MAS VENDIDOS" with the best seller items (removing the "tabs", just titles)

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the template of your theme:

go to `themes/<your_theme>/modules/`

Find the `blockbestsellers` directory.
Inside this directory, you'll find a `tab.tpl` file, empty it.

Then in the `blockbestseller-home.tpl` file wrap the `if` statement with a row:

```
<div class="row">
   the content already present
</div>
```

Do the same for `blocknewproducts` module

These modules should now be displayed on two rows on your home page